# Why is the "Queens Gambit" referred to as a gambit?

Tags: opening, queens-gambit

If White will just get a pawn back at no cost, why is the `Queens Gambit` a `Gambit`?  Is it for historical reasons or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it's just because it looks like a mirror version of the King's Gambit, nothing more.

Comment: That's not really correct. It is indeed a gambit: that then Black cannot permanently hold to the pawn doesn't make it any less of a gambit.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco: this isn't exact science, terms like "correct" are too strong. Is the Scotch Opening misnamed because black can win a pawn with 4...Qh4? Is the Two Knights Defence misnamed because white wins a pawn in the main line of 4.Ng5? Four years later I still think that 2.c4 has the name it has because of the King's Gambit.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that a gambit involves a sacrifice in no way means that the sacrifice is permanent. Very few mainline gambit openings for White leave the gambit player with no means of retaking his material.

While [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_%28chess%29) does not necessarily make the distinction between a gambit and a sacrifice, I would contend that there is a difference:

- A sacrifice is intended as a permanent loss in material in exchange for a superior position.
- A gambit is a temporary loss to hasten development or secure a position.

Based on this understanding, there is no reason NOT to consider the Queen's Gambit as a true gambit, unless you wish to state arbitrarily that there must be more than X number of plies between the loss and the subsequent regaining.

Answer (score 8):

> A Gambit is a chess opening where *a pawn is sacrificed in order to grab the initiative*.

The Queen's Gambit is called a Gambit because White sacrifices the `c-pawn` in order to get a better control over the center.

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 d5 2.c4 dxc4
```

After Black has accepted the pawn with `dxc4`, the consequence is pretty clear i.e., without a pawn on `d5` Black has less control over the center squares `e4` and `d5`. White can use this fact and soon play `e2-e4`, `Nb1-c3` and `Bf1-c4` to control these squares.

Practice has shown that *accepting the gambit is not the best option for Black*. Therefore, many opening systems have been developed where the gambit could be declined, mainly using `2. ..e6` or `2. ..c6`.

Answer (score 0):

A gambit by any other name is still a gambit. Using your pawn as a sacrifice in order to control the action/ space on the board is the choice of the player. I concur w/ the notion that it’s not necessarily a sacrifice if the means justify the ends. Basically, it’s just a term that has been assigned to a particular strategy... is all!!!